# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GOTO, expecting T_STRING or '(' in a/b/c/function.php on line 406

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [syntax error, unexpected T_GOTO, expecting T_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258697/syntax-error-unexpected-t-goto-expecting-t-string)

I've uploaded this but it shows error:

```
<?
    function goto($url="") {
        echo"<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;url=$url\">";
    }
?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GOTO, expecting T_STRING or
>   '(' in /a/b/p/function.php on line 406.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: no disrespect, but did you even read the error code? searching google for "syntax error, unexpected T_GOTO, expecting T_STRING" gives the a solution right away... even on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258697/syntax-error-unexpected-t-goto-expecting-t-string

Answer (score 2):

`goto` is a php keyword, you can't use it as function name. Just change name of your function e.g.:

```
<?php
    function meta_refresh($url = "") {
        echo"<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;url=$url\">";
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks it works anotherquery is what i use every time instad of goto?

Comment: Yes, this is your function, I've just changed its name.

Answer (score 2):

The word `goto` is reserved in php, since it is the name of a builtin function. You just have to use another name for your function, that's all.

Comment: thanks it works anotherquery is what i use every time instad of goto?

Comment: It is a function you yourself define for your own purpose. Usually it is a good idea to use a name that reflects what a function does. Maybe something like `loadUrl()` or `redirectTo` in this case? You can give it any name you want, as long as it is not amongst the few reserved words every programming language has: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php